# Is there any software that has the same vector drawing tools as Flash?

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, drawing, tracing

I was wondering if there is any software that has the SAME vector drawing tools that flash has/had. I tried photoshop and a couple of other programs but the main thing is that you would have to use the pen tool to make the lines into curves.

In flash the workflow was simple you would draw a straight line then click and drag to transform it to a curve. I used this feature alot to trace images to a vector and was able to trace a fairly complex image in minutes .

thanks

Comment: You would need to try them to see what work for you.. there are a *slew* of vector apps... Photoshop is **not** one of them. Photoshop is a **raster** app with a few vector tools. Not the same. Try Illustrator, Inkscape, CorelDraw, Sketch, Xara....

Comment: Thank you Scott , i appreciate your response

Comment: I don't know if you maybe asked this question just to look for alternatives or because you thought the Adobe Flash Pro doesn't exist anymore because flash video format is dead... etc, but you know it does still exist. [Adobe Flash Pro was renamed to Adobe Animate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Animate#Versions). So it does still exist, it just tries to be a more generic animation software that can export to multiple formats. So I'd say try that... assuming you weren't looking for an alternative for other reasons.

Comment: You can [bend straight lines in Inkscape](https://imgur.com/Gf4UuOj), which is free and open source. Inkscape isn't animation software however.

Answer (score -3):

Try Figma, everything you need in vector. Also cross platform and browser ver.

Comment: Hello Ivan, welcome to GDSE. We typically look for long answers. While short answers are fine when they are to the point, we typically look for longer, substantiated answers. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer and include _why_ you'd recommend Figma? Why is it a good fit to the asker's issue? Are there any downsides to it? You are welcome to take the [tour] to get to know the site a little better, anything else you can find in the [help].